# css3 - animation/keyframes browser issue

Tags: css

I am having some problems when running this animation in Chrome:

```
.login-loading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #19bee1;
}
.login-loading:after {
  content: '';
  background: trasparent;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) -4px -5px 3px -3px;
    -webkit-animation:rotates 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation:rotates 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation:rotates 2s infinite linear;
  animation: rotates 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotates {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotates {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotates {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotates {
  0% {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

It's a loader which have a spinning "tail". My issue is that the animation is not moving/running. I am using Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari and Chrome are using the attribute `-webkit-transform`.

The solution is to add on every `transform` attribute a `-webkit-transform` attribute.

Comment: +1 Good catch. In addition: Note that Safari doesn't support animations on pseudo elements at all. See here for [browser support](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)